# Project Euler 14 - Java StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

For those unfamiliar with the problem, [here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) it is.

I am getting a StackOverflowError with the following code:

```
public class LongestCollatzSequence {

static int count = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int range = 1000000;
    int maxSeq = 0;
    List<Integer> chainList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= range; i++) {
        generateSequence(i);
        if(chainList.isEmpty()) {
            chainList.add(count);
            count = 1;
        } else if(!chainList.contains(count) && count > Collections.max(chainList)) {
            chainList.clear();
            chainList.add(count);
            maxSeq = i;
            count = 1;
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("Sequence starting number: "+maxSeq);
}

private static void generateSequence(int num) {
    if(num == 1) {
        return;
    }
    if(num % 2 == 0) {
        count++;
        generateSequence(num/2);
    } else {
        count++;
        generateSequence(num*3+1);
    }
}
```

}

High level flow:

-For numbers 2 - 100000, generate a collatz sequence for that number.
-Chain list is a list to store the length of the sequence generated for each number i.e. sequence size for number 13 is 10 (see example).
-If the current sequence size is bigger than the max in the chain list, clear chain list and add the new max, also store the value of i in maxReq to remember the starting number that produces the longest chain.

Comment: Post the exact exception in full (including stack trace).

Comment: Use an iteration instead of recursion.

Comment: in which line do you take this error

Comment: Oh, come on folks.  We don't need the stack trace or the exact line of the error.  A stack overflow is a stack overflow.

Comment: You can greatly improve the performance, by avoiding generating the sequence of a number more than once. Cache the sequence length for a number once you get it. You can use a `Map` for that. And then in another sequence, if you get the number in between, whose length you've already calculated, you can stop there, and use it. BTW, you shouldn't really be using recursion here. Just follow iterative approach.

Comment: Just to concur with the comments above use iteration and [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem but the int in java is limited to 2^31-1 you could crox this limit use long or BigInteger

```
  private static void generateSequence(long num) {
    if (num == 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        count++;
        generateSequence(num / 2);
    } else {
        count++;
        generateSequence(num * 3 + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The max value you will start at is 1,000,000. I doubt any would break integer overflow. The highest I came across was around 4,000,000 IIRC.

Comment: Oh, I see.  So probably an `int` overflow made `num` negative at some point, then sent the process into a cycle.  +1 for spotting this.  But even with this solution, it's possible that `num` has become negative but not gone into a cycle.  It seems that the only correct thing to do is to make `num` a `BigInteger`, not `int` or `long`.

Comment: Yes BigInteger is the best. I used long just to test the overflow

Comment: @DavidWallace For the given range, `long` will be enough. I'm saying this because I've done this problem. ;)

Comment: But you can't prove that the overflow hasn't happened, even if the program terminates.  You honestly don't know whether `long` is enough or not, unless you check at each step that `num < Long.MAX_VALUE / 3`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yeah that is true. And that is why I said, "I'm saying this because I've done this problem." ;)